# android studio asks to add dependency on module even after adding dependency

Tags: android, android-studio

i have to use the LibWizardPager library in my appliction. I have added a dependency to my android application.

[image]

LibWizardPager module is added as a dependency to my project still android studio shows error and ask to add LibWizardPager as dependency.

[image]

when the dependency is added again the error goes but the project still wont run. it gives class does not exist error.

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The LibWizardPager was no set as a library in the build gradle

changing `apply plugin: 'android'` to `apply plugin: 'android-library'` fixed the issue